# How to call the ajax function in my plugin file using wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to call the ajax call in my plugin . I have created plugin file .

My Plugin File :-

```
  class Wp_MYplugin{
        function __construct() {
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax', 'my_ajax' );
        }

        function my_ajax(){
            echo "test";
        }
   }
```

Ajax call returns 0 . How can I fix this ?

Comment: Add more code, the question is unclear at the moment. Where is the javascript part (actuall AJAX call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In end of ajax function please write `die;`
and 
 if you are using same class for calling ajax function then you must have to write `array( $this,'my_ajax' )`.

**For Example:**

```
class Wp_MYplugin{
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax', array( $this,'my_ajax' ) );
    }

    function my_ajax(){
        echo "test";
        die;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax', array( $this, 'my_ajax' ) );`

Within class you need to add `$this` within array. and end the function with `exit;` or `wp_die();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax', array( $this, 'my_ajax' ) );
```

$this is used with in a class..

Hope it will Work